# Dapper stopped pulling joined table after updating the table with a stored procedure

Tags: sql, asp.net-core, stored-procedures, dapper

Because I was having this error

> InnerException = {"Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Loan' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF."}

So I decided to change it to this stored procedure.

```cs
this._context.Loan.FromSqlInterpolated($"Exec CreateNewLoan @CurrencyCode = {loan.CurrencyCode}, @OperativeAcctNo = {loan.OperativeAcctNo}, @AmountWrittenOff={loan.AmountWrittenOff}, @OriginalLoanAmount={loan.OriginalLoanAmount}, @LoanTrfDate={loan.LoanTrfDate}, @InterestRate={loan.InterestRate}, @LoanAccountNo={loan.LoanAccountNo}, @DRCR={loan.DRCR}, @CustId={loan.CustId} ");
```

Which is inserting the record successfully, after inserting the page will redirect to the index page and call another method to pull the list and display with this dapper query

```cs
public async Task<IEnumerable<Loan>> GetAll(bool includeDeleted, bool showUnapprovedOnly)
{
    IEnumerable<Loan> loans = null;

    try
    {
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
        {
            await conn.OpenAsync();
            //
            string sql = "Select l.*, c.FirstName_CompanyName from dbo.Loan l left join Customer c on  l.CustId=c.CustId";
            if (!includeDeleted)
            {
                sql += " and l.Deleted = 0";
            }
            if (showUnapprovedOnly)
            {
                sql += " and l.Approved = 0";
            }

            loans = await conn.QueryAsync<Loan>(sql);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        throw;
    }
    return loans;
}
```

There is a relationship between the Loan and customer table. The customer Id(CustId) is also inserted with the stored procedure. I noticed the customer names of the newly inserted records are not being displayed. the previous ones are showing. I don't know why new records are not pulling the customer table\

```
   public class Loan
    {
        public int LoanId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name ="Customer Name")]
        public long CustId { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        [Display(Name ="Customer")]
        public string FirstName_CompanyName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Currency Code")]
        [StringLength(10)]
        [Required]
        public string CurrencyCode { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Loan Account No.")]
        [Key]
        public string LoanAccountNo { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Branch Code")]
        [StringLength(5)]
        public string BranchCode { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Amount Written Off")]
        [Required]
        public double? AmountWrittenOff { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [Display(Name = "Loan Tranfer Date")]
        [Required]
        public DateTime? LoanTrfDate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Interest Rate")]
        [Required]
        public double? InterestRate { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("CustId")]
        public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Was _CustId_ inserted correctly in _dbo.Loan_ table by _CreateNewLoan_ stored procedure or _NULL_ was inserted? If _CreateNewLoan_ is a problem, please, share stored procedure SQL code

Comment: Yes, the CustId was correctly inserted and the column for CustId is also inserted. other columns are showing on the view table. It's only the new Customer names that are not showing. The CustId is referencing the Customer Table. Previous Customer names columns are showing correctly

Comment: If the CustId was correctly inserted, then problem could be related to Dapper mapping. Please share the code that reads the data.

Comment: This is the code ```string sql = "Select l.*, c.FirstName_CompanyName from dbo.Loan l left join Customer c on  l.CustId=c.CustId";``` This code was working correctly before I change the identity. The person that originally worked on this project made CustId identity which is also referencing Customer Table. Later I discovered customer can request loans more than once. So I have to change it and create a new auto-generated Identity. I don't know is that could be the cause?

Comment: Do you have Multi-Mapping code to map correctly? It should looks like [this example](https://dapper-tutorial.net/query#example-query-multi-mapping-one-to-one).
Please, share Dapper mapping code

Comment: I have updated my question with the complete dapper code

Comment: You should also show the `Loan` class. Seems like you expect some reference property to be populated.

Comment: I have updated with the Loan class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like *FirstName_CompanyName* wasn't mapped to any class property.
This mapping change should fix the problem.

```cs
var sql = "Select l.*, c.CustId, c.FirstName_CompanyName as Name from dbo.Loan l left join Customer c on  l.CustId=c.CustId";
var loans = connection.Query<Loan, Customer, Loan>(
        sql,
        (loan, customer) =>
        {
            loan.CustomerName = customer?.Name;
            return loan;
        },
        splitOn: "CustId")
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Kindly check my updated question with the Loan class. Loan and Customer classes do not have CustomerName and Name that property respectively. The

Comment: When I step over the code, on the second iteration, I got ```customer.FirstName_CompanyName threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException```

Comment: I've updated `customer.Name` to `customer?.Name` to fix `NullReferenceException`